Normal to submanifold defined by a set of functions and divergence theorem
I have a submanifold $\Sigma(\mathbf{z})$ defined using a set of functions $\mathbf{q}(\mathbf{x}) = (q_1(\mathbf{x}), ..., q_m(\mathbf{x}))$. Let $\mathbf{z} = \mathbf{q}(\mathbf{x})$, and $\Sigma(\mathbf{z}) = \{\mathbf{x}: \mathbf{q}(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{z}\}$. I have an integral of this form:
$$ \int_{\Sigma(\mathbf{z})} \left( \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} \right) d\sigma_\Sigma(\mathbf{x})$$
where $\sigma_{\Sigma}(\mathbf{x})$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\Sigma(\mathbf{z})$. I now wish to apply the divergence theorem to this to obtain the surface integral
$$ \int_{\Sigma(\mathbf{z})} \left( \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F} \right) d\sigma_\Sigma(\mathbf{x}) = \int_{S_{\Sigma(\mathbf{z})}} \left( \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} \right) dS_{\Sigma(\mathbf{x})}$$
Firstly, does applying the divergence theorem in the context of a submanifold make sense? If yes, how do I calculate the normal vector $\mathbf{\hat{n}}$?
